# DataStructure:How implement print to splay tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I try to implement a splay tree by java. [The code](https://ideone.com/bfUt2C).

Ordinary, binary search tree's print:

```
public void printTree(BinaryNode<AnyType> node){
    if(node != null){
        printTree(node.left);
        System.out.println(node.element);
        printTree(node.right);
    }
```

But print each node should invok splay() method, and right child tree and left child tree of node will transform.

Comment: You should be able to find the StackOverflowError if you catch the exception and examine the stack trace. Or, you could use your debugger and trace execution. Apparently you have an infinite recursion situation going on.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel My coder is no problem,when NUMS is 40000 lead to infinit recursion return **StackOverflowError**.